# How to load CSV file with thousands of rows in the Knowledge Feature of Dialogflow?

Tags: csv, dialogflow-es, session-timeout, connection-timeout, beta

Whenever I load my csv file containing **3568 rows** on the ***Knowledge (Beta)*** feature of Dialogflow, an error prompts informing me about an **Operation Timeout**. I thought that it might be due to the number of rows on my csv that is why I tried to create a separate file containing only 20 rows and it was processed.

Is there a way to change the **timeout** so that I can load my csv file in one go? I am trying to avoid the solution of creating a new csv for every 20 rows just to load it in the tool. Kindly refer to the image on the link below. Thanks much, I hope for your response soon.

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Are you following the right document [structure](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.Document) for your csv? Update your question with your csv file content structure.

Comment: Hi @SudheeshR, Yes, I followed the required documents structure for my csv file _**(No headers, 1st column - questions, 2nd column - answers)**_. It is working if there are only 20 rows. Is there a way for me to load all 3568 rows besides grouping them to 20 rows?

Comment: You can parse up to 2000 QA pairs in one document. Try to reduce your rows to 2000 and try again. And please mind that 'Duplicate questions with different answers is not supported'.

Comment: Hi @SudheeshR. I tried reducing it by 1000 rows. Unfortunately the issue still persist.

Comment: Could you update your question with 2 rows of your csv ? And are you sure that you don't have any duplicate questions in your csv?

Comment: yep already tried it and no duplicate questions since it contains unique names.

Comment: ok could you update question with your csv sample data ?